# Can you show a public leaderboard without calling to GamesClient.connect()?

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is it possible to show a leaderboard from my game if the user is not logged in with google plus?

I'm using GamesClient, and it seems we need to call connect() first and have them log in:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#connect()

before you can use:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#getAllLeaderboardsIntent()

but I've noticed the vast majority of my users don't choose to connect.

I'm thinking it'd be nice to show the public leaderboard even if the user is not connected. This would get them interested in connecting with gplus and competing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

You can show leader-borads in 2 ways: pre-build intent provided by the SDK, where you only need to call the intent and magic arises. And calling the `GamesClient.loadLeaderboardMetadata(...)` method that returns a JSON with all your leader-boards (then you'll have to call `GamesClient.loadTopScores()` or one of its variants to get the scores).

The problem is that both methods get info from the public charts and the social ones, so before getting the info, the service needs to know who the player is.

You can always request to add this as an enhancement to the SDK.